# How to put the table inside the box

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am doing a website just for learning purposes of css of other templates, and I am doing a table with 8 attributes.

I need some guidance on how can I put the table inside the box, without it going out of the borders. I tried to put overflow, but I think I am doing it wrong. 
The template is from the internet.

I think I just have to do something in tablesorter, but am not sure what.

```
#este .tablesorter {
  width: inherit;
  margin: -5px 0 0 0;
}

#este .tablesorter td{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
}

#este .tablesorter thead tr {
  height: 34px;
  background: url(../images/table_sorter_header.png) repeat-x;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#este .tablesorter input[type=image] {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

#este table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, 
#este table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
  background-color: #8dbdd8;
}
```

The code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/3gnhfLLt/

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering, Everybody had correct answers, Thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table headers `<th>` are simply to long. You have 3 options:

1. Use scrolling in x direction:

   ```
   .module_content {
       overflow-x: auto;
   }
   ```
2. Use max-width on table cells with `break-word`:

   ```
   th {
       max-width: 30px;
       word-wrap: break-word;
   }
   ```
3. Make table header cells content smaller

Answer (score 1):

Put `overflow-x: auto` to the `module_content` class and there you go!

```
.module_content {
    margin: 10px 20px;
    color: #666;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Comment: oh, thats true, and I was mingling with the table. How stupid of me. would it be possible if I wanted to increase the size of the bx, instead of overflowing x axis?

Comment: well, Google chrome is having problems with the overflow solution

Comment: i couldn't find any... could you please give an updated fiddle so that we can check?

Comment: The same example, with the     overflow-x: auto; line.  if I try to view the page with IE it comes correctly.

Comment: inside fiddle, it gives me the same result, in dreamweaver(using for development) its not giving the same result with chrome only.

http://jsfiddle.net//yhm5oct9/ the fiddle link

Comment: maybe something is going on in the dreamweaver IDE?

Comment: it works fine with IE, dont know what happened in chrome. I noticed that it is not updating the overflow line in css ,  in browser chrome when i inspect code

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your css and will definitely work

```
.module_content{
  overflow-x:auto;
  width:auto;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gnhfLLt/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#este .tablesorter {table-layout:fixed; width:100%;}

#este .tablesorter td, #este .tablesorter th{ word-wrap: break-word;}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/wdquouyf/1/)